# Does adding Android jars to a jogl or Java 3d project cause problems?

Tags: java, android, swing, jogl, java-3d

Ive rebuilt a project I once ran on an older Mac and have added the Android jars because I wanted to migrate to that in the future and test it in the project. The program executes but Swing applications, JOGL, and Java 3D programs no longer open or Render. There may be continuous processes. Will they ever execute or what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By adding Android jars I assume you mean the Android SDK. Adding these to a Java project **will** break it as Java != Android. (This part has been discussed countless times in chat and questions. The JDK is not the same as the Android SDK, different bytecode, etc)

Swing doesn't exist in Android. Neither does Java3D<sub>1</sub>. Android either relies on the embedded OpenGL ES support, a framework (e.g. LibGDX), an engine (e.g. Unity) or something like LWJGL to access OpenGL API's. Note that Android runs OpenGL **ES**, which basically is a light-weight OpenGL (less API's is one difference)

JOGL does have Android support, and it looks like it's easier to convert as the API's aren't separated

In addition, android has a completely different system compared to Java. For an instance, there are Activities, the main method isn't used, there are layouts (either .xml or creating a new instance of a View object, for an instance a SurfaceView or a GLSurfaceView, but a Button would also work)

My point is, if you want to convert a desktop OpenGL project into Android, you have to re-write most of it due to major API differences.

So they will not execute unless you take steps to make it runnable on Android. And you're better off starting a new project to make sure you get all the dependencies an Android project needs (the sdk is one thing, but there's also the manifest, the gradle plugin, etc)

<sub>1: Java3D has some support for Android, but it's not a fully functional API yet</sub>

Comment: Sorry to contradict you but Java3D 1.7.0 has some Android support (being implemented by Phil, our new maintainer). JOGL doesn't have a strong separation between "desktop API" and Android, it has its own OpenGL ES binding, the only major difference is the use of a dedicated activity. Making two separate projects to make a distinction between Android and other supported platforms is the way to go but you can still make a third project, parent of the both, in order to store the common source code, this is the main interest of using JOGL in projects for Android in my humble opinion.

Comment: @gouessej so JOGL has non-separate bindings while Java3D has a barely functioning one. Still doesn't change the fact that there are differences in how it's made

Comment: JOGL 2 has its own windowing toolkit called NEWT which doesn't require AWT, it's an excellent candidate under Android as AWT is unsupported (Swing too, I agree with you). It allows to write OpenGL ES code running under desktop and embedded environments. In my humble opinion, it would make no sense to have to use different APIs to interact with OpenGL ES and JOGL even contains some subsets of functions supported both in OpenGL and OpenGL ES, for example com.jogamp.opengl.GL2ES2.

Comment: My point is, if you want to convert a desktop OpenGL project into Android and if you use NEWT with a common subset of OpenGL and OpenGL ES, you will still have to create separate projects for OS specific source code as JVM != Dalvik Virtual Machine / Android RunTime but you can still keep the OS agnostic source code unchanged. "you have to re-write most of it " is true only if most of the code uses APIs only supported by Java and not by Android. I don't deny that Java and Android use different toolsets, packaging methods, etc...

Comment: Maybe this post helps: http://forum.jogamp.org/Recreating-Jogl2-Android-demo-projects-in-Eclipse-td4027079.html#a4027138